# Navbar desktop to mobile

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a navbar hamburger in mobile view. But The issue is, I have two ULs, and when I created a hamburger The two `UL`'s will split into mobile versions. Is there any way I can fix that thing?

This is my code:

```html
<header>
  <div class="container" id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div id="nav-toggle">
          <a href="#">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-auto">
          <span class="navbar-title">PRACTICE FOR NAVBAR HAMBURGER</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="navbar justify-content-center" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active hometext disabled">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#shop">SHOP</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext">BLOG</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <div class="navbar" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I wanted to stay the desktop view as this

[image: Desktop view]

The first `<ul>` is in the HOME section then the second `<ul>` is MY ACCOUNT

Comment: can you include the `css` as well? Also, are you using any CSS framework?

Comment: wrap both ul with another outer ul.

Comment: As for navbar's no I dont use any, I only use css for the colors for now @Yong

Comment: @MinSomai can you give me some example? Sorry im new to this projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` for a div that includes two ul:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar1{
  width: 60%;
}
.navbar2{
  width: 30%;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav1 li{
  width: 20%;
}
nav2 li{
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar1 justify-content-center" id="nav">
  <ul class="nav1">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active hometext disabled">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#shop">SHOP</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link hometext">BLOG</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link hometext">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link hometext">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="navbar2" id="nav">
    <ul class="nav2">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#">1<i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#">2<i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hometext" href="#">3<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it not going to split when mobile hamburger version? I tried using 2 separate divs

Comment: @新Acesyyy What's your mean by `split`? that means they go under each other?

Comment: When I used two separate divs I don't know but they go like `<ul>` `<title>` `<ul>` just like that

Comment: @新Acesyyy I used `flex` without `flex-wrap` so this should work correctly. You can test that and to say the result.

Answer (score -2):

I think the best solution is to wrap both of your ul into a single one in mobile screen sizes using JavaScript

Comment: Sorry but how can I do that? Can you give me some documents for that or examples sites that I can learn? Im kinda new with this